# please help me out with mac OS 10.11 terminal commands

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm new to using mac. Could someone please help me out with the terminal commands?

cd to jump into folders right?
i tried this but it isn't working for a folder in my desktop.
Basically, I want to enter a folder on my dekstop and then go to another folder inside that. how do i do it?

Answer (score 3):

The Terminal starts in your `HOME` folder normally. So, type

```
ls
```

to list the files and you will see the same folders and files you see when you go to `HOME` in the Finder. So, you will see `Desktop`, so now type

```
cd Desktop
ls
```

and you will see all the folders and files on your desktop. If you want to go into one called `Freddy Frog` now, you will need to put double quotes around it to make sure the space between `Freddy` and `Frog` is kept and it doesn't think you want to go to a folder called `Freddy` then one called `Frog`. so type

```
cd "Freddy Frog"
ls
```

and you can now go to the `"Spiders from Mars"` directory in there with

```
cd "Spiders from Mars"
ls
```

In general, you can just start typing the name of the folder you mean and press `TAB` and it will guess what you mean. So, if you start a new Terminal and type:

```
ls
```

you will see the files in your Home directory. Now type:

```
cd Desk<TAB>
```

and it will show you what it guesses you mean. That's called `filename completion`. If you want to know where you are currently located, use:

```
pwd
```

which will print the working directory.

If you want to return to your HOME directory at any time, just type:

```
cd
```

Two other tips for you if you are learning your way around...

Firstly, if you want Finder to open and display the directory you are currently in in the Terminal, you can run:

```
open .
```

[image]

Secondly, when Finder opens, you can turn on the `Path bar` at the bottom of the window by typing:

```
Command+Option+P
```

I have shown it in red - no idea why Apple ships with it turned off by default - probably explains why most Mac users I have met generally have no idea where their files are and don't know the difference between copying and moving files!

Comment: I added a couple more tips to get you started.

Answer (score 1):

To change directory to say /usr , the command should be  `cd /usr`
i.e. cd followed by the absolute path of the directory. For relative paths use `cd ./usr` where the directory usr is in your current directory.[This](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucd.htm) link gives complete documentation of cd command.

Answer (score 0):

Use the change directory command:

- using relative paths `cd ./relative/path/to/directory`
- using absolute paths `cd /absolute/path/to/directory`

**IMPORTANT: do not to forget the space after `cd` and before the path!!!!!**

On Windows, the space isn't needed for some reason...